# ffmpeg not working from php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I installed the version from http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.5.3.tar.bz2
and also tried the yum version but it is not new enough for youtube-dl.

I tried `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` and PHP/Apache still cant find FFmpeg.

Apache user runs PHP script on CentOS 6.5.
Calling my youtube-dl.php from php command line as root works (with FFmpeg)
Calling my youtube-dl.php from php apache user works (not with FFmpeg)

What I am trying to do: shell exec youtube-dl (youtube dl calls FFmpeg in its binary code which there is now to modifiy it to add the full path). This works but the FFmpeg part
my youtube-dl.php file

```
$output = shell_exec('youtube-dl -o "/home/test/%(title)s.%(ext)s" '.$url.'      -f bestvideo+bestaudio 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

# which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Someone on other pages on this site says local/bin is for customized versions but I downloaded it directly from FFmpeg and did the standard ./configure make install.

Done:

```
 chmod 755 to /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Running FFmpeg as a test command directly (sometimes works and doesn't as I upgraded/rebooted/updatedb/etc)

```
$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Result:

```
<pre>sh: ffmpeg: command not found</pre>
```

I read all of these similar questions but they didn't help:

> FFMPEG PHP does not seem to work
>   FFmpeg not working
>   Recording audio with FFMPEG works in terminal but not through exec() of PHP
>   ffmpeg-php permission denied on localhost
>   C++ program from PHP not working properly
>   FFMPEG works from command line but not PHP
>   Calling a shellscript from php - not working correctly
>   PHP Internal Server Error 500 when using ffmpeg to convert files
>   PHP code not proceeding to the line after exec ffmpeg
>   ffmpeg not working from php script but works from command line
>   PHP exec() Not Working With ffmpeg
>   ffmpeg not work with PHP exec()
>   ffmpeg php exec not working

Comment: How does `shell_exec` fail? Do you get some error message? If you don't, try capturing `stderr` from shell_exec and see what it contains.

Comment: where would i put the stderr  command?

Comment: There error you get is `ffmpeg: command not found` so ou need to make sure shell can access `ffmpeg`. See for instance: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: [youtube] ehcVomMexkY: Downloading js player en_US-vflqnkATr
WARNING: Writing cache to u'/var/www/.cache/youtube-dl/youtube-sigfuncs/js_en_US-vflqnkATr_40.41.json' failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.cache'

[youtube] ehcVomMexkY: Downloading DASH manifest
WARNING: You have requested multiple formats but ffmpeg or avconv are not installed. The formats won't be merged
[download] Destination: /home/test/f264.mp4

Comment: WARNING: You have requested multiple formats but ffmpeg or avconv are not installed. The formats won't be merged

Comment: would this be a solution? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere

Comment: thanks but this where it gets confusing: PATH=$PATH:~/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg 
PATH=~/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg:$PATH  what would go where

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg    and php apache still cant find ffmpeg

Comment: Your `PATH` is bogus; it should be `/usr/local/bin`. What output do you get when you run `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg from command prompt opens ffmpeg

Comment: shell exec ffmpeg sh: ffmpeg: command not found from php

Comment: shell exec /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ffmpeg version 2.5.3 (works from php) but youtube-dl calls ffmpeg internally - ffmpeg is registered as a global program but apache not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution what worked for me.
I followed the tutorial here to install ffmpeg: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

Set up the PATH then I checked ffmpeg –version from command prompt it was working.

Then I tried to download a 1080p video with youtube-dl (youtube link) -f bestvideo+bestaudio but I got the same message: "WARNING: You have requested multiple formats but ffmpeg or avconv are not installed. The formats won't be merged." Of course it was installed.

Then I opened the command prompt with Run as Administrator, tried the same and it worked finally.

Comment: First off, welcome to stack overflow! Linking to documentation or tutorials is a great idea. But links can break. So always try to outline the answer on S.O. as well. (Even just the basic steps without the details below will suffice!) :)

Answer (score -2):

- **Step 1 :** `cd ..`
- **Step 2 :** `cd /usr/bin`
- **Step 3 :** `wget http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/32bit/ffmpeg.static.32bit.latest.tar.gz`
- **Step 4 :** `tar -xvzf ffmpeg.static.32bit.latest.tar.gz`